# how to make groups of positive sign groups and negative sign groups

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

dataframe have column A , i want to check when continuous values are negative group and positive values group ,

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,-1203,-159,-35,0,0,0,0,205,-11,0,0,0,-145,-14,-12,0,182]}


Negative values group 1
0,-1203,-159,-35,0,0,0,0

positive values group 1
205

Negative values group 2
-11,0,0,0,-145,-14,-12,0
positive values group 2
182
```

Comment: Do you need new column? What is expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can try this

```
df['val'] = np.where(df['A'].gt(0).cumsum().diff().fillna(0).ne(0),'posgrp','ngrp' )
```

**Output**

```
A       val
0       ngrp
-1203   ngrp
-159    ngrp
-35     ngrp
0       ngrp
0       ngrp
0       ngrp
0       ngrp
205     posgrp
111     posgrp
-11     ngrp
0       ngrp
0       ngrp
0       ngrp
-145    ngrp
-14     ngrp
-12     ngrp
0       ngrp
182     posgrp
```